# Fortify Java Http Request Header Manipulation

Tags: java, security, httprequest, owasp, fortify

I read some data from httprequestservlet headers,in fortify static fortify analyze I got

Header Manipulation vulnerabilities issue.What is the best way to fix request header manipulation for fortify issue

```
String a=(requestServlet.getRequestURL().toString());
String myId =requestServlet.getHeader("MyID");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this page https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.dataflow.java.header_manipulation, I think you need to add the sanity check for the header parameters.

Normally the fortify server will give the fix suggestions. for example, they explains the path manipulation as below

[image]

Comment: is validate header value is enough here?

Comment: it is depending on the context. in fact, if you get the header value in the code and don't sanitize it, the potential attacker could put a value to override the real response. you have the example on the link above. if it is a customized header, you have the constraint on the value I think. for example, the value must be alphanumeric. you could verify and sanize the value of this header.